# Dajax log warning

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

I'm install both Dajaxice and Dajax with sucess (they both works)
But i get some warning in dev server log

```
The 'request' object must be accesible within the context. You must add 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request' to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and render your views using a RequestContext.
```

If i try to add to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request

it will raise error about **no context_processors.request in  django.contrib.messages**

Also i render my templates with context like

```
return render_to_response('root.html', {'news' : news, 'author' : author }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My log section in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
   'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
'dajaxice': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
'dajaxice.DajaxiceRequest': {
'handlers': ['console'],
'level': 'INFO',
'propagate': True,
},
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change

```
django.contrib.messages.context_processors.request
```

to

```
django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages
```

It's `messages` not `request`

Comment: It just came up on /review as being too short. I thought your original answer was pretty clear :)

Comment: Is this sufficient? You might rewrite it, but the messages() processor is going to add a "messages" entry to the context, not the "request" item that dajaxice wants: "request = context.get('request')"

Comment: @catherine Reread my comment. You're repeating exactly what's said above, which doesn't fix the problem. The data inserted into the context by -that- processor is not the same as the data inserted by the one now missing.

Comment: According to [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/) `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages` is now added by default, however I still have the warning.